# What is the Maximum File Name Length of Picture on Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I'm curious about whether there is a maximum file name length of a picture on a Windows Phone device. If my application was to name a picture with a certain convention, I would not like to exceed the maximum character limit. Also, are special characters allowed in picture file names (if so I may use special characters instead of a certain character set in my own app's naming convention).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly an expert in the topic but I believe it is 260 characters. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Seems to be right.  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-US/6aa88257-dfe4-4ddb-a11c-0417758d49d8/max-characters-of-the-file-name-stored-in-the-isolated-storage  
One remark to add - 260 characters refers to whole path, not only filename.

Comment: Ok one question, this wouldn't be in my application's IsoStore, but the picture (and its respective name) would be stored on the device's default Photos Hub. Does it have the same character and length requirements? Also, can the name include special characters like `$` or `&`?